# Importing a standard color into blender (gamma correction issue?)

Tags: color, color-management

I'm having issues with rendering exact colors. So I'm working on an archviz project and there are certain objects that require a specified standard color. Basically the color on render has to match the color on the standard very precisely. My issue is, that if I were to copy rgb values, the rendered color would not be the same (due to gamma correction I assume). I've found online that setting color management to standard will fix the issue, but doing that jeopardizes the photorealizm.

So in my specific case I've been told to use a color from NCS. It's a standard color, which has the following properties:
[image: RGB: 81, 119, 101, HEX: #517765]

By simply pasting the hex values into blender will output wrong colors:
[image: Color difference]

So I understand that light will also interact with the material and make a difference, but I need to make the base color in Blender to really match standard color. What are the options? Is there a way for me to manually convert color from sRGB to linear space so it still looks the same when in Blender? What are the possible workarounds?

Comment: *"doing that jeopardizes the photorealizm"* - you can't eat a cookie and have a cookie. The sRGB/filmic is a transformation happening at the very end of the pipeline, so either you want the colors distributed in linear fashion (the energy of light), or in sRGB fashion (shift the colors so that e.g. 20% darkest colors take 50% possible values) or Filmic fashion (squeeze hell lot of very bright colors into the saved range).

Comment: As I understand your problem, you want to render as you already do, but you want to achieve a particular color on a particular surface in the output file. Kind of like achieving white color in filmic means setting the value of the color (each channel value) to its celing value `16.291740238…`. So you need to apply a reverse transformation on your color and input that as the value, correct?

Comment: More reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46825/60486

Comment: Yes, I'd like to reverse transformation my color and input that as value, which will allow me to use filmic for better photorealizm and at the same time make the color accurate (there will be color variation - darker and lighter because of bump, which is completely fine)